# If $f(x^2)-f(x)^2\geq \frac14$ for every $x$ then $f$ is not injective

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that there is no real-valued injective function $f$ such that, for every $x$: $$f(x^2)-f(x)^2\geq \frac14$$

I set $x=0$ and $x=1$ and got that $f(0)=f(1)=\frac12$ and for these values $f(x^2)-f(x)^2=\frac14$. But how can these results be extended or lead to the final conclusion?

Comment: What about the constant function $f = 1/2$?

Comment: @TheoBendit - You would get $1/2-1/4$ which is indeed $\ge1/4$

Comment: @YvesDaoust I determined the sign of a quadratic polynomial

Comment: This problem has come from a persian text having no solution: it's real origin is from a contest in Romania in 1981

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi Please, look if there are other hypothesis in that text

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi - This is completely wrong: any $f=1$ then you have that $1-1=0$

Comment: I forgot to say : $f$ is injective! Everyone: I'm sorry

Comment: if $f(0)=f(1)$ then $f$ can not be injective.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Read better: The only real solution to $t-t^2\geqslant\frac14$ is $t=\frac12$ hence if $x^2=x$ then $f(x)-f(x)^2=f(x^2)-f(x)^2\geqslant\frac14$, thus $f(x)=\frac12$, end of the proof.

Comment: @Did Although it seems that the result was known from OP, I think you should make an answer of your comment and simply add that then injectivity can not hold.

Comment: @Surb Hmmm... I only expanded your comment, right?

Comment: @Did I think you expanded the observation of OP more than my comment and this was the only tricky part. But the community wiki post seems to be a good compromise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an answer under community wiki:

You proved that $f(0)=f(1)=\frac12$ which concludes the proof as it implies that $f$ can not be injective.

For completeness, we note that $f(0)=f(1)=\frac12$ follows from the fact that for $x\in\{0,1\}$, it holds $f(x)=f(x^2)$ and thus
\begin{align*}
\frac14 \leq f(x^2)-f(x)^2 = f(x)-f(x)^2\qquad &\implies \qquad \big(f(x)-\frac12\big)^2\leq 0 \\ &\implies\qquad  f(x)=\frac12
\end{align*}